# Continuous onkeydown event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, onkeydown

I have a regular onkeydown event handler that fires a function, like this:

```
window.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
```

It essentially works, but it only captures 1 key in Firefox. Then I have to release it and press again.

Google chrome offers me a continuous grab, so I wonder if this is by choice.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `keypress` event? The `keypress` event is fired after `keydown` if the key is held down.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try something like this:

```
var iskeydown = 0;
var samplecount = 0;

function onKeyDown() {
    iskeydown = 1;
    while (iskeydown) continuous();
}

function onKeyUp() {
    iskeydown = 0;
    alert(samplecount);
}

function continuous() {
    samplecount = samplecount + 1;
}

window.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
window.onkeyup = onKeyUp;
```

Made better:

```
var iskeydown = 0;
var samplecount = 0;

function onKeyDown() {
    iskeydown = 1;
    continuous();
}

function onKeyUp() {
    iskeydown = 0;
    alert(samplecount);
}

function continuous() {
    if (iskeydown == 1) {
         samplecount = samplecount + 1;
         setTimeout("continuous()",200);
    }
}

window.onkeydown = onKeyDown;
window.onkeyup = onKeyUp;
```

Comment: Doesn't seem a great idea: it will place unnecessary stress on the JavaScript runtime, could produce the "This script is taking a long time" warning and could prevent the browser from handling new key events.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you must be using a Mac or Linux, because in Windows, Firefox does support auto-repeated `keydown` events. In other operating systems, however, you only get auto-repeated `keypress` events when you hold a key down. In summary, if you can, use the `keypress` event.

See [Jan Wolter's excellent article on JavaScript key events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) for more information.